# GCS Connector for Spark Issue - Error getting bucket

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform

I want to enable Spark to export data to Google Cloud Storage, instead of saving it on HDFS. To achieve this, I have installed [Google Cloud Storage Connector for Spark](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/tree/master/gcs). Here's a sample code inside a Spark context, which I use to save a dataframe to a bucket:

```
val someDF = Seq(
  (8, "bat"),
  (64, "mouse"),
  (-27, null)
).toDF("number", "word")

val conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
conf.set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")
conf.set("fs.gs.project.id", PROJECT_ID)
conf.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable", "true")
conf.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.json.keyfile", LOCATION_TO_KEY.json)

someDF
  .write
  .format("parquet")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .save(s"gs://BUCKET_GLOBAL_IDENTIFIER/A_FOLDER_IN_A_BUCKET/)
```

I receive a rather cryptic exception after the code is executed:

```
java.io.IOException: Error getting 'BUCKET_GLOBAL_IDENTIFIER' bucket
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl$8.onFailure(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:1633)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.BatchHelper.execute(BatchHelper.java:183)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.BatchHelper.lambda$queue$0(BatchHelper.java:163)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageExceptions.createJsonResponseException(GoogleCloudStorageExceptions.java:82)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl$8.onFailure(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:1624)
  ... 6 more
```

Could anyone give me a clue on how to tackle this? Here's a list of issues I've already solved, to get to this point:

- The key could not be accessed by Spark. The issue was that it was not available on physical nodes, which Spark was run on.
- GCS service account, used for the Spark connector, did not have a permission to create a bucket. The issue was solved by saving the data to an already existing bucket.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you missed double-quotes in the end of the line .save

You have:

```
save(s"gs://BUCKET_GLOBAL_IDENTIFIER/A_FOLDER_IN_A_BUCKET/)
```

But the correct would be:

```
save(s"gs://BUCKET_GLOBAL_IDENTIFIER/A_FOLDER_IN_A_BUCKET/")
```

The error is that your variables are being treated as strings instead of variables most likely because you missed the quotes.